# Conversion of Krups Nespresso Machine to Ground Coffee?

Tags: espresso-machine, coffee-machines, nespresso

I have inherited a Krups Nespresso machine model F893. The machine has a detachable filter basket, where you sit the Nespresso capsule. Manual here (for reference): [manual](https://manuall.co.uk/krups-f893-espresso-machine/)

I am wondering if I can swap out the filter basket holder for one that takes a basket of ground coffee, like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Krups-Espresso-Machine-963-972-Primo-Original-Part-Filter-Holder-Basket-Black-/372350848524). The fittings look superficially similar.

Or just shove a basket for ground coffee in the current filter basket holder?

Has anyone tried this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could get a reusable nespresso capsule [Like this](https://www.amazon.de/Wiederbef%C3%BCllbare-Nespresso-Kaffeekapsel-Edelstahl-Nachf%C3%BCllen/dp/B071GPRBK4/ref=sr_1_8?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3LE2UYPC3TI7H&keywords=reusable+nespresso+capsules&qid=1566816687&s=gateway&sprefix=reusable+nes%2Caps%2C171&sr=8-8).
Its a little bit more effort when you want to make your espresso but it would be the simplest and probably cheapest option for you. 
 But this comes with some disadvantages too, like the capsule can only hold 5 grams of coffee, maybe 6.